# Translating C++'s sprintf format string to C#'s string.Format

Tags: c#, c++, printf, string.format

I found the following C++ code (comments added myself):

```
// frame_name is a char array
// prefix is std::string
// k is a for loop counter
// frames is a std::vector string
sprintf(frameName, "%s_%0*s.bmp", prefix.c_str(), k, frames[k].c_str());
```

I then try to translate it to C#

```
// prefix is string
// k is a for loop counter
// frames is List<string>
string frameName = string.Format("{0}_(what goes in here?).bmp", prefix, k, frames[k]);
```

Basically, what would be the C# equivalent of the C++ format string "%s_%0*s.bmp"?

Edit, @Mark Byers:

I've tried your code and made a little test program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> frames = new List<string>();
    frames.Add("blah");
    frames.Add("cool");
    frames.Add("fsdt");

    string prefix = "prefix";
    int n = 2;
    int k = 0;
    string frameName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.bmp", prefix, frames[k].PadLeft(n, '0'));
    Console.WriteLine(frameName); // outputs prefix_blah.bmp, should output prefix_00blah.bmp
    Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

It's not padding for some reason.

Edit: Got it working; won't pad if n = 2.

Comment: Are you sure you want to reuse `k` for two different purposes?

Comment: Are you sure about those format strings? Specifically: `%0*s` - the `0` modifier in conjunction with the `s` conversion is, according to the man page here, undefined behavior.

Comment: That's what I was given when looking at an open-source program.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that what you are given is correct. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pad a string with zeros use [**`string.PadLeft`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx):

```
frames[k].PadLeft(n, '0')
```

In combination with [**`string.Format`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
int n = 15; // Get this from somewhere.
string frameName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.bmp",
                                 prefix,
                                 frames[k].PadLeft(n, '0'));
```

Note that I have changed `k` to `n`, as I assume that this is a bug in the original code. I think it's unlikely that the length of the padding on the file name was meant to increase by one in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks, but apparently it's not padding; see original post.

Comment: @thebackup: It's not padding because you've set n = 2. n is the minimum length. If you just want to add two zeros always that is much easier and doesn't need the PadLeft function.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now; it works as expected - it's just what I wanted in the first place. Thanks very much, Mark.

Answer (score 1):

For formatting details like the `0*` in `%0*s`, I'd do it this way:

```
string.Format("{0}_{1}.bmp", prefix, frames[k].PadLeft(k,'0'));
```

If I have it right, it will take `frames[k]`, and left-pad it with 0's.

e.g.:

```
k=10;
frames[k] = "Hello";
frames[k].PadLeft(k,'0') ==> "00000Hello";
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: The * in `%0*s` requests that a parameter be used to specify the precision. Thus, 1 for `%s`, 1 for the `*`, and 1 for the `%0*s`, or 3.

Comment: Except `0` with `s` would appear to be UB - see my comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks, going to test out the code; I'll let you know how it turns out.